# Compare and count in ubuntu

Tags: grep, awk

I have a file with 2 columns like this:

```
Product Cost
ab        5
ab        7
bl        1
bl        8
ce        4
```

I want to search for "ab" and "bl" and then need to sum up the Costs for them and need to show which one is greater

I have tried 
(grep "ab" myfile | numsum -c 2) and (grep "bl" myfile | numsum -c 2) but unable to compare their sum and print the result. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '/ab|bl/{s[$1]+=$2} END{for (k in s) print "sum of",k,"is",s[k]; if (a["ab"]>a["bl"]) print "ab is greater"; else print "bl is greater";}' myfile
sum of ab is 12
sum of bl is 9
bl is greater
```

#### How it works

- `/ab|bl/{s[$1]+=$2}`

  For lines that contain either ab or bl, sum column 2.
- After we have finished reading myfile, use `print` statements to display the results:

  ```
  END{
      for (k in s) print "sum of",k,"is",s[k];
      if (a["ab"]>a["bl"])
          print "ab is greater"
      else 
          print "bl is greater";
   }
  ```